# How can I send data via Ajax to different elements?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

script.js

```
 $(document).on("click", ".send", function (event) {
   $.ajax({
            url: "update.php",
            data: {
               id: id,
            },
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                $(".blue").html(data);
                $(".red).html(data);
            }
        })
 });
```

update.php

```
echo "this text should go to blue";
echo "this text should go to red";
```

index.php

```
<button class="send">Send</button>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="red"></div>
```

On one Ajax request I want to send data to two different divs. I have no idea how to solve this. Or if is this possible? I tried that with two different Ajax requests. But because I need to get data from the database, this causes conflicts.

---

Here the updated code according to the suggestions:

```
   $(".send").click(function(){
      $.ajax({
            url: "update.php",
            data: {},
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                $(".blue").html(data.blue);
                $(".red").html(data.red);
                  alert("success");
            }
        })
});
```

update.php

```
$array['blue'] = "blue content";
$array['red'] = "red content";
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($array);
```

---

UPDATE:

Like this the code is working:

Update.php

```
$array['blue'] = "blue content";
$array['red'] = "red content";
//header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($array);
```

scipt:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "update.php",
            data: {},
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                //$(".blue").html(data.blue);
                //$(".red").html(data.red);
                $(".red").html(data);
                  alert("success");
            }
        })
```

Then my result in the red div is:

```
{"blue":"blue content","red":"red content"}
```

Comment: Send json back from your php script instead of html (could be json with values containing html...).

Comment: @jeroen Ah, ok, I do not know json. Will take a look at it

Comment: if this is all your code u shud get `Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined`

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile in reality the id is defined. I just didn't write the details because it is not important for this example

Comment: Ok good then. @iceman answer should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the server pack the data as JSON, and unpack it on the client.

Simple Example:

update.php

```
$array['blue'] = "blue content";
$array['red'] = "red content";
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($array);
```

script.js

```
$(document).on("click", ".send", function (event) {
   $.ajax({
            url: "update.php",
            data: {
               id: id,
            },
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                $(".blue").html(data.blue);
                $(".red").html(data.red);
            }
        })
 });
```

Comment: Cool! Didn't know that. Will check it out immediately

Comment: Someone downvoted. Pls explain why if you don't mind. Good for everyone!!

Comment: I still cannot get it run in my code. I do not know why

Comment: @Jarla change `$(".red).html(data.red);` to `$(".red").html(data.red);` then the code will work.

Comment: I just ran it thru jshint and had found it.

Comment: I tested on my local machine, its working as expected!

Comment: wok on my side as well...  just made few changes, will post them as a comment here, I won't post a new answer when there's a working answer

Comment: maybe @Jarla u can add `dataType : 'json', encode : true,`

Comment: I am desperate. It is not working for me. It is only working when I replace all the json code on update.php to for example `echo "test"` and replace `$(".blue").html(data.blue);$(".red").html(data.red);` to ` $(".red").html(data);`

Comment: I also tested with `dataType : 'json', encode : true,`

Comment: as soon as I add `header('Content-type: application/json');` or `dataType : 'json', encode : true,` my button is not working anymore

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Yes, I will post it in my question in 1 minute

Comment: Well, I posted the actual code I have in my question. Right now "success" is NOT alerted...

Comment: remove data completely `data:{}` remove i

Comment: I did that, but still no luck

Comment: Seems to be a problem with json encoding?

Comment: I'm back. sorry had to go in b/w. can you tell what is the exact error you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

Also another working solution

```
var jsonUrl = 'update.php';
        $.ajaxSetup({
            cache: false
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: jsonUrl,
            data: {},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $('.blue').html(data.blue);
                $('.red').html(data.red);
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                $('.red').html('error fetching data');
            }
        });
```